# Add generate password button in symfony add user admin panel form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, vue.js

**First problem:** i want to add `Generate` password button under password text input. 
[image]
code:

```
class UserAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    ...

    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) :void
    {
        if ($this->getFormAction() == 'create')
            $formMapper
                ->add('email')
                ->add('plainPassword', TextType::class);

            $formMapper->add('enabled');
    ...
```

I tried to include ButtonType and add `->add('button', ButtonType::class);`
after `plainPassword` input but i got error:

> The options "label_render", "property_path",
>   "sonata_field_description" do not exist. Defined options are: "attr",
>   "auto_initialize", "block_name", "disabled", "label", "label_format",
>   "translation_domain".

Other try by add button in twig: in `custom_edit.html.twig`

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:edit.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="generate_password">Generate password</button>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script src="{{ asset('build/admin.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

but button show above the form and won't be easy to handle the action since i use vue:[image]

---

**Second problem:** i use this [password-generator](https://github.com/hackzilla/password-generator) lib i want when i click `Generate` button ^ the value of `plainPassword` input changes to new password every each click. here is code:

```
class UserAdminCRUDController extends Controller
{
    ....
    public function generatePassword()
    {
        $generator = new ComputerPasswordGenerator();

                $generator
                    ->setUppercase()
                    ->setLowercase()
                    ->setNumbers()
                    ->setSymbols(true)
                    ->setLength(9);

                return $generator->generatePasswords(1);
    }
    ....
```

Comment: For first - read about the [customization of forms rendering](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html). And for second - you can use ajax to send request to the required action.

Comment: Your issue about button descripbed on [github](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/3072)